# Long strings and keeping full words CSS issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap typical div container. I have two problems to solve:

1. Not allowing long strings to overflow the div contrainer
2. To keep words not braked, like if word reaches limit, full word goes below

This is what I've got:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

It basically works for not letting long strings to overflow the div, but cut words in peaces, like:

```
something, somethi
ng, something, som
ething, etc.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `word-break: break-all;` 
Use `word-break: normal;`. it will work.

Comment: Hey viks, thanks. Unfortunately it does not work :/ td's are extended (overflown), to the same end of the longest string, having it as normal.

Comment: Can you add one fiddle for it? so it will help to look at your html also.

Comment: Hm, seems it works on fiddle, so your remark was great, thank you! I'll figure out why it does not work at me, but at least I know it should :)